# MultiOutputClassifier only returns learned data

Tags: python, machine-learning

As the title says, I am testing python MultiOutputClassifier, to fix a problem that requires determining coordinates (x,y) as output, given 3 inputs and it only returns as prediction the closest learned value, not the 'extrapolated' one.

My sample is code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

train_data = np.array([
[-30,-60,-90,0,0],
[-50,-50,-50,10,0],
[-90,-60,-30,20,0],
[-50,-50,-95,0,10],
[-60,-30,-60,10,10],
[-95,-50,-50,20,10],
])
# These I just made up
test_data_x = np.array([
  [-35,-50,-90],
])

x = train_data[:, :3]
y = train_data[:, 3:]
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=1)
classifier = MultiOutputClassifier(forest, n_jobs=-1)
classifier.fit(x,y)
print classifier.predict(test_data_x)
```

This returns 0,10, but I would expect that for the given inputs the output should be something like 5,5; somewhere between two of the learned values.

I see that there is something I am doing wrong or I misunderstood. Any help with this issue? Is it that the MultiOutputClassifier is not the right thing?

Comment: You are using a classifier, not a regressor. In this way you are getting either `[0,0]`, `[10,0]`, `[20,0]`, `[0,10]`, `[10,10]` or `[20,10]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that a (Random Forest) Classifier won't extrapolate. It can only output values it has already seen. You probably want to use a regressor.

Replacing "Classifier" with "Regressor" in your code yields (0.8, 5.8) as output, which seems closer to what you expected.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor

train_data = np.array([
    [-30,-60,-90,0,0],
    [-50,-50,-50,10,0],
    [-90,-60,-30,20,0],
    [-50,-50,-95,0,10],
    [-60,-30,-60,10,10],
    [-95,-50,-50,20,10],
])

test_data_x = np.array([
    [-35,-50,-90],
])

x = train_data[:, :3]
y = train_data[:, 3:]
forest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=1)
classifier = MultiOutputRegressor(forest, n_jobs=-1)
classifier.fit(x,y)
print(classifier.predict(test_data_x))
```